# How to Extract Part of a String In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, wordpress

I am using a chunk of jQuery code that returns a selected option from a group of image icons. It is integrated into the WordPress WYSIWYG Editor.

When I click on the icon this string is sent to the editor:

```
image="'+ $('.icon-option i.selected').attr('class') +'"
```

This code returns: `fa fa-heart selected`

From this string I want to remove the string `selected` so that it just reads `fa fa-heart`.

I tried: `image="'+ $('.icon-option i.selected').attr('class').split(' ')[0] +'"` but it cut the string off at `fa`

Is this an easy fix that can be added on to my original jQuery String manipulation call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for string manip, use the [`removeClass`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) method:

```
$('.icon-option i.selected').removeClass("selected");
```

If you then also need the string of the class names you can expand to:

```
$('.icon-option i.selected').removeClass("selected").attr("class");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by doing:

`image="'+ $('.icon-option i.selected').attr('class').split(' selected')[0]`

Comment: Perfect @rkho. Thanks for the very prompt response. Works perfectly. I thought I was close.